# Uploading to Apple App store "Invalid Custom Intents"

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

Uploading an update for an existing app I received an email detailing the recent issues. The 'NeighbourOrders.strings' file is unchanged in this version.

> Invalid Custom Intents - The 'NeighbourOrders.strings' file in the '/Payload/MyApp.app/fr.lproj' folder is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue from 2-3 days. Please give me the resolution if you already found.

Comment: Afraid I deleted that strings file entirely. Not a very pleasing solution I know.

Comment: oh! But I can not delete that file. :(

Comment: Apple developer have a thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109309

Comment: Yes but there is no solution yet.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Please let me know the solution, if anyone have

Comment: I fixed this problem by recheck every line in .string file it's must ending with semicolon.

Comment: They deleted every answer to this question(?), so use @benmore99's solution above if anyone want a solution

Comment: @benmore99 I checked my string file, it is ending with a semicolon, but still having this issue..

Comment: @Bhupesh  semicolon after each line?

Comment: @stevenpcurtis Yes.